# Inequality about a function in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and bounded, nonzero only on $Q \subseteq \{x_n > 0\}$.

Then due to fundamental calculus theorem 
$$ f(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \int_0^{x_n} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} (x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}, t)\;  dt$$

Now my textbook says that, if   $\; d=\operatorname{diam} Q$, this implies that
$$ | f(x_1, \dots, x_n)|^2 \leq d \int_0^{x_n} \left| \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} (x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}, t)\right| ^2 \;  dt$$

My question is: why is the $d$ necessary? Intuitively I'd say that the estimation makes sense also without it.

Comment: hint: Cauchy Schwarz on $\int 1 \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n} f (..., t) dt$

Comment: Same thing the book says, but how

Comment: what exactly does Cauchy Schwarz say and how could you split the function under the integral such that it looks like the statement in Cauchy Schwarz?

Comment: Oooooh, $1*$the function. Damn I'm rusty on this stuff. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without $d$, the inequality is false. Say, for $n=1$ (which is, obviously, the only case you need to consider) it would read
$$
|f(x)|^2 \le \int_0^{x} |f'(t)|^2 dt.
$$
For $f(x) = x$, this would imply that 
$$
x^2\le 4x^3/3,
$$
which is certainly false for small $x$.

In order to prove it with $d$, apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, as user251257 suggested.